# Opengl performance issue when drawing polygon meshes

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, optimization, opengl-es

I'm using the following code to draw some polygon meshes in a 3D game.

```
void drawModelFace(const MeshFace *face, float *vertices, float *vertNormals, float *textureVerts)
{   
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int i = 0; i < face->_numVertices; i++) 
    {
       glNormal3fv(&vertNormals[3 * face->_vertices[i]]);

       if (face->_texVertices)
       {
           glTexCoord2fv(&textureVerts[2 * face->_texVertices[i]]);
       }

       glVertex3fv(&vertices[3 * face->_vertices[i]]);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

My problem is that I'm experiencing some performance issue ingame when this function is called a lot of time.

This function is called on average 50000 times per second which gives a constant 60fps but on some places it's called 100000 times per second which gives a 15fps. (I'm using a today's computer underclocked to 1Ghz to simulate the performance of today's phone)

I heard that immediate mode could be slow that's why I tried using glDrawArrays instead. Here's the code:

```
void drawModelFace(const MeshFace *face, float *vertices, float *vertNormals, float *textureVerts)
{   
    GLfloat vert[3*face->_numVertices];
    GLfloat normal[3*face->_numVertices];
    GLfloat tex[2*face->_numVertices];

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vert);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normal);

    for (int i = 0; i < face->_numVertices; i++) 
    {
        vert[0 + (i*3)] = vertices[3 * face->_vertices[i]];
        vert[1 + (i*3)] = vertices[3 * face->_vertices[i]+1];
        vert[2 + (i*3)] = vertices[3 * face->_vertices[i]+2];

        normal[0 + (i*3)] = vertNormals[3 * face->_vertices[i]];
        normal[1 + (i*3)] = vertNormals[3 * face->_vertices[i]+1];
        normal[2 + (i*3)] = vertNormals[3 * face->_vertices[i]+2];

            if (face->_texVertices)
            {
                tex[0 + (i*2)] = textureVerts[2 * face->_texVertices[i]];
                tex[1 + (i*2)] = textureVerts[2 * face->_texVertices[i]+1];
            }
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN ,0, face->_numVertices);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); 
}
```

But the performance results are exactly the same.

How can I optimize my code to gain some fps?

Note that my final goal is to use this code an android devices thus glBegin and glEnd are not allowed anymore.

Comment: You appear to be working out how to draw a mesh in the actual draw function rather than beforehand.  What I mean is your draw function should simply be passed the arrays already constructed.  So the problem here is more how you're managing your model workflow than anything else.  I would make sure you have a VBO and an index buffer for each mesh.  Then you won't have to iterate around the mesh in the middle of drawing.  You just chuck a soup of triangles and indices at the graphics card.

Comment: In ES 1.1 your options are pretty limited. It's glDrawArrays and glDrawElements, and that's about it. Also, the PC architecture is significantly different from a embedded device. An underclocked CPU with a x16 PCIe bus and a NVIDIA board in unlikely to give the same performance than a PowerRV.

Answer (score 4):

I think that glDrawArray may be the best option. If I remember correctly, the data from the arrays will be sent from the client to the server in each iteration. If the the data is changed in each iteration, then that is not really an issue, since the client needs to send the data to the server each time it is changed anyway. This means that due to the implementation of VBOs, storing large chunks of data on the server memory, will not really give you any performance gains since you will have to resend  that data anyway.

Are you using large objects or many small ones?
I am fairly confident that glDrawArrays are most optimal in situations with large objects.

What exactly do you mean with "performance results are exactly the same."? is it very very similar or is there any difference? It sounds a bit suspicious to me that if performance is exactly the same.

Comment: FYI, the followup questions in this answer are better posted as comments to the original question (instead of in your answer).

Comment: I'm using many small objects as there are only 3 or 4 vertices each time the function is called.

Comment: The performance gains from using gldrawarrays is then mitigated by  the fact that there are many objects. The biggest advantage of gldrawarrays is that the client can send very large amounts of data to the server very quickly and then go about with the next line of code and let the server handle the huge amounts of data it just got received. This is opposed of using glBegin/glEnd where the client needs to wait between each glvertex call (atleast that is how I understand it, maybe Im wrong tho).

Comment: So using many small objects will still cause a holdup in the client, since it needs to send arrays many times, instead of one big array once. having many small objects that are being changed often is more or less the worst possible situation performance wise. You might want to think of alternative solutions where you can group your data together logically in your app. Using VBOs and many small objects is also, I think a bad idea.

Comment: Also you might want to rethink how you are altering the vertices. If you can change the position of the vertices in a group, you can get performance by using the glrotate/gltransform/glscale calls on for example a VBO instead of changing the values in a gldrawarray and sending it in each iteration

Comment: @vincentthuning glDrawElements is most optimal with large objects, not glDrawArrays

Comment: Good point, but isnt the main difference that gldrawelement has support for indices and gldrawarray doesnt?

Comment: I tried to reduce the number of calls of the glDrawArrays function just to check the performance. I divided by two the number of calls which means I draw only half the model and the game is now fullspeed! Now my main problem is to find out how to draw the entire model with this setting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh doesn't change (i.e. it's a static model) then you could use a [display list](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenLists.xml)

This allows you to pre-compose all your vertex/texture/normal calls into a list which you then render with a single function call to glCallList.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a static model, moreover display list are not part of opengl-es 1.1 which is my final goal. Someone told me about vertex buffer objects but I'm not sure how to implement this in my code.